# limit of a matrix product

Tags: matrices, limits

I'm trying to show that the limit of a particular matrix product approaches another matrix. The first is of the form:

$$G =mA\Bigl(B+(A'A)m\Bigr)^{-1}$$

The second is of the form:

$$H=(AB^{-1}A')^{-1}AB^{-1}$$

Where $m$ is a scalar, $A$ is a $k\times n$ matrix with $k << n$ and $A'A$ is singular. $B$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix.  Both $G$ and $H$ are well defined. I want to show the following:

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}G=H$$

Numerically this limit works but I'm not sure how to prove it. I've tried various tricks with factoring and I've thought that I may have to resort to very carefully writing out the matrix products and examining terms but would really like to avoid this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: Here's how I started one approach but it didn't get me too far: $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} G = mA\Bigl((I+mA^{'}AB^{-1})B\Bigr)^{-1}=mAB^{-1}(I+mA^{'}AB^{-1})^{-1} =AB^{-1}(\frac{1}{m}I+A^{'}AB^{-1})^{-1}=AB^{-1}\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{m}I+A^{'}AB^{-1})^{-1}$

Comment: maybe there is some way to apply power series to this to get what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us write

$$G_{m} = G = mA (B + mA^{*}A)^{-1} $$

in order to clarify that $G_{m}$ depends on $m$. Then we claim that $G_{m} \to H$ in operator norm. To this end, we first check the following two simple lemmas:

> **Lemma 1.** Let $J = (AB^{-1}A^{*})^{-1}$. Then we have
>   $$ G_{m}
> = J \left( AB^{-1} - \frac{1}{m}G_{m} \right)
> = H - \frac{1}{m} JG_{m}. \tag{1} $$

*Proof.* We consider $J^{-1}G_{m} = AB^{-1}A^{*}G_{m}$ instead. Simplifying this, we get

\begin{align*}
AB^{-1}A^{*}G_{m}
&= (AB^{-1}A^{*})(mA)(B + mA^{*}A)^{-1} \\
&= AB^{-1}(mA^{*}A)(B + mA^{*}A)^{-1} \\
&= AB^{-1}\{(B + mA^{*}A) - B\}(B + mA^{*}A)^{-1} \\
&= AB^{-1}\left( I - B(B + mA^{*}A)^{-1} \right) \\
&= AB^{-1} - AB^{-1}B(B + mA^{*}A)^{-1} \\
&= AB^{-1} - \frac{1}{m}G_{m}.
\end{align*}

Multiplying $J$ to both sides, we obtain $\text{(1)}$ as desired. ////

> **Lemma 2.** For $m > \| J \|$, the matrix $1 + m^{-1}J$ is invertible and we have the following estimate
>   $$ \left\| (I + m^{-1}J)^{-1} - I \right\| \leq \frac{\| J \|}{m - \| J \|}. \tag{2} $$

*Proof.* Let $u \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$ be any vector. Then

$$ \| (I + m^{-1}J) u \| \geq \| u \| - \| m^{-1} J u \| \geq (1 - m^{-1}\| J \|) \| u \|. $$

In particular, if $m^{-1}\| J \| < 1$, this shows that $I + m^{-1}J$ is injective, hence bijective. This proves that $I + m^{-1}J$ is invertible. Moreover, in this case we can replace $u$ by $(I + m^{-1}J)^{-1} u$ and we get

$$ \left\| (I + m^{-1}J)^{-1} u \right\| \leq \frac{1}{1 - m^{-1}\| J \|} \| u \|
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad
\left\| (I + m^{-1}J)^{-1} \right\| \leq \frac{1}{1 - m^{-1}\| J \|}. \tag{3} $$

On the other hand, we have

$$ \left\{ (I + m^{-1}J)^{-1} - I \right\} (I + m^{-1}J)
= I - (I + m^{-1}J)
= -m^{-1}J. \tag{4} $$

Thus combining $\text{(3)}$ and $\text{(4)}$, it follows that

$$ \left\| (I + m^{-1}J)^{-1} - I \right\|
= \left\| -m^{-1} J (I + m^{-1}J)^{-1} \right\|
\leq \frac{\| J \|}{m} \frac{1}{1 - m^{-1} \| J \|}. $$

Therefore we get the estimate $\text{(2)}$ as desired. ////

> *Remark.* Lemma 2 is a direct consequence of the [*Neumann series*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) for $(1 + m^{-1}J)^{-1}$.

---

Now we return to the proof.

> **Proposition.** $G_{m} \to H$ in operator norm as $m \to \infty$.

*Proof.* Rearranging $\text{(1)}$, we get

$$ (I + m^{-1}J) G_{m} = H. $$

This if $m$ is large, then $G_{m} = (I + m^{-1}J)^{-1} H$ and hence we get

$$  
\| G_{m} - H \|
\leq \left\| (I + m^{-1}J)^{-1} - I \right\| \| H \|
\leq \frac{\| J \| \| H \|}{m - \|J\|}
\xrightarrow[]{m\to\infty} 0. $$

Therefore the proposition follows. ////

Comment: this is a really nice proof, thank you

Comment: this proof my end up in a paper, can I note your contribution?

Comment: @evgeny, Sure! I'm glad it helped you!

Comment: actually, I think the 2nd step in Ingredient #2 is missing something.  I don't see how you are able to factor out $AB^{-1}$.  I think I found an alternative but I checked your formula numerically and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @incog55, Please check my calculation which is now detailed. And I also checked this with Mathematica for tens of cases and there was no problem there.

Comment: you're right! my mistake.  My other question is in regard to claim #1.  Aren't you missing the $m$ that is supposed to multiply the outside A matrix? Without this $m$, I agree that your choice of $C$ is independent of $m$ but otherwise, it seems that you've shown that $\frac{1}{m}G_m \leq C$?  I'm probably missing something in your argument but please let me know

Comment: @incog55, You're absolutely right. I fixed both the claim and the proof of main proposition. Thankfully, I was able to make amend of my proof. Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: yea, this is really good! One question on a possible simplification: You show that $I+m^{−1}J$ is invertible using the injective property. I believe we could also do this using a power series expansion: $I−m^{−1}J+m^{−2}J^2−m^{−3}J^3...$ As you claim, for $m>||J||$, this series will converge but can we also say that as $m\rightarrow \infty$ this inverse will approach $I$ and hence we wouldn't need the rest of Lemma2?

Comment: @incog55, Yes, you are completely right. And that's what my *Remark* says. I was not sure if you know Neumann series or not, so I tried a direct proof.

Comment: thanks, as my comment clearly shows I did not know about nuemann series :)